# Use time zone of device

Tags: java, android

In my app i want to get the time zone of device and then use it in simple date format, here is my code:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();


        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") ;
        sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
```

i am getting correct id and display name from tz but the code does not works correctly for time.

Comment: worked around little bit and got it working:

Comment: this worked for me:Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone;
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") ;
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getDisplayName()));

Answer (score 2):

you should use `TimeZone.getDefault()`

it returns a TimeZone based on the time zone where the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `TimeZone` of the `SimpleDateFormat` so that it prints out a time in your local timezone, but the `'Z'` at the end prints out a literal letter Z, which means UTC. You should remove the quotes around it so that it prints the actual timezone at the end, e.g. `+0100`.

That said, you haven't mentioned whether you're using the `SimpleDateFormat` for printing or for parsing.